# Parallax/Steller.js and Jquery Waypoints

Tags: jquery, parallax, jquery-waypoints

I'm playing around with Stellar.js and used the demo found here:
http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/complete-websites/create-a-parallax-scrolling-website-using-stellar-js/

I'm running into the same problem that the demo page has, which is, when the page first loads, the navigation (slide 1) is not active. It only becomes active once you start scrolling down, then when you return to slide 1, it remains active.

This is an issue found in FireFox and IE8 (don't have IE9 to test on).

I'm sure its a waypoint issue, and not activating on page load. How can I fix it so that "Slide 1" in the navigation goes to it's active class state?

Here is the JS code from the demo:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {


//initialise Stellar.js
$(window).stellar(
    {
    // Set scrolling to be in either one or both directions
    horizontalScrolling: true,
    verticalScrolling: true,    
    // Refreshes parallax content on window load and resize
    responsive: true,   



    }
    );

//Cache some variables
var links = $('.navigation').find('li');
slide = $('.slide');
button = $('.button');
mywindow = $(window);
htmlbody = $('html,body');



//Setup waypoints plugin
slide.waypoint(function (event, direction) {

    //cache the variable of the data-slide attribute associated with each slide
    dataslide = $(this).attr('data-slide');


    //If the user scrolls up change the navigation link that has the same data-slide attribute as the slide to active and 
    //remove the active class from the previous navigation link 
    if (direction === 'down') {
        $('.navigation li[data-slide="' + dataslide + '"]').addClass('active').prev().removeClass('active');
    }
    // else If the user scrolls down change the navigation link that has the same data-slide attribute as the slide to active and 
    //remove the active class from the next navigation link 
    else {
        $('.navigation li[data-slide="' + dataslide + '"]').addClass('active').next().removeClass('active');
    }

});


//waypoints doesnt detect the first slide when user scrolls back up to the top so we add this little bit of code, that removes the class 
//from navigation link slide 2 and adds it to navigation link slide 1. 
mywindow.scroll(function () {
    if (mywindow.scrollTop() == 0) {
        $('.navigation li[data-slide="1"]').addClass('active');
        $('.navigation li[data-slide="2"]').removeClass('active');
    }
});

//Create a function that will be passed a slide number and then will scroll to that slide using jquerys animate. The Jquery
//easing plugin is also used, so we passed in the easing method of 'easeInOutQuint' which is available throught the plugin.
function goToByScroll(dataslide) {
    htmlbody.animate({
        scrollTop: $('.slide[data-slide="' + dataslide + '"]').offset().top
    }, 2000, 'easeInOutQuint');
}



//When the user clicks on the navigation links, get the data-slide attribute value of the link and pass that variable to the goToByScroll function
links.click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    dataslide = $(this).attr('data-slide');
    goToByScroll(dataslide);
});

//When the user clicks on the button, get the get the data-slide attribute value of the button and pass that variable to the goToByScroll function
button.click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    dataslide = $(this).attr('data-slide');
    goToByScroll(dataslide);

});
```

});

any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take a look at the functions that are available with the [jQuery Waypoints plugin](http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/#docs).

The first is try setting the waypoints plugin's **offset** setting slightly (http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/#doc-disable). This will make the waypoint trigger at a different point of the page, so that even if you are at the top of the screen, the first waypoint will trigger.

```
//Setup waypoints plugin
slide.waypoint(function (event, direction) {

dataslide = $(this).attr('data-slide');

if (direction === 'down') {
    $('.navigation li[data-slide="' + dataslide + '"]').addClass('active').prev().removeClass('active');
}    
else {
    $('.navigation li[data-slide="' + dataslide + '"]').addClass('active').next().removeClass('active');
}
}, { offset:50 }); // The waypoint is triggered when the element is 50px from the top of the viewport.
```

Or you could just add the 'active' CSS class to the first element that will then be changed on scroll.

Hope that helps ya.

Comment: Thanks, the switching of the styles actually worked better than trying to get the JS to work in FireFox and IE 8.

Answer (score 0):

You could also just add the class in the html, since the script removes the class as you scroll away from the first element anyway.